# Specify explicit type for imported symbol in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I'm importing data from JSON file in my TypeScript module:

`import data from './data.json';`

This is supported via `resolveJsonModule` option in `tsconfig.json`.

However, is there a way to specify a type for imported symbol this way?

e.g.: `import data: DataInterface from './data.json';`

The only way I know is this:

`const rawIconDefinitions: RawIconDefinitionsMap =
  require('../icons-data.json');`

But, I would prefer to use declarative ESM syntax if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Use module augmentation documentation and add a .d.ts file with this signature

```
declare module 'data.json' {
    const value: any;  // your type here
    export default value;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've created an `types/index.d.ts` in my project, but TypeScript is not picking it up. It still infers the type from the actual JSON data. What could be wrong? I even tried to specify `types` property in `tsconfig.json`.